# How to rename upload image while uploading - Flask / Python

Tags: python, flask

I´m building a website where people should be able to add small adds with pictures. All pictures go to the same directory. So I need to rename the pictures so there wont be any overrides or conflicts.

When I´m adding an add to the website its auto increment the add_id. I want to use this add_id for the picture name.

```
def allowed_file(filename):
return '.' in filename and \
       filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/aufgeben', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
    titel = request.form['titel']
    beschreibung = request.form['beschreibung']
    kategorie = request.form['kategorie']
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit a empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    # Anzeigeninhalt in DB eintragen
    cursor = g.con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('insert into anzeigen (titel, beschreibung, kategorie) values (%s, %s, %s)',
                   (titel, beschreibung, kategorie))
    g.con.commit()
    cursor.close()
    flash("Anzeige aufgegeben.")
return render_template('aufgeben.html',)
```

Thanks for all help. Maybe someone have a better idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can use current timestamp.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply.
how can I add the timestamp to the picture name?

Comment: In file.save() function it seems that the second argument is the file's name, Why don't you change it?

Comment: Ok, I´ll test it and let u know. Thanks all

Comment: What was the conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be too late for a response but maybe someone else will look for an answer. As Nishant Nawarkhede replied, you can use timestamp to rename the files uploaded. Since I came accross the same need I used the following piece of code to rename the files while uploading:

```
NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
new_filename = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename.rsplit('.',1)[0] + '_' + NOW.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S") + '.' + file.filename.rsplit('.',1)[1])
```

After this, your files should look like the following format:

> 'path_to_file/filename_datetime.jpg'